# Selecting values from 2 tables and 1 condition

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables: professionals, speciality and session. Every professional has an speciality and has made certain quantity of session.

let's say...

```
professionals           
| id | name |        
...........         
| 1  | John |        
| 2  | Bart |        
| 3  | James|        


speciality                  
| id |profId|desc |       
..................       
| 1  |   1  |neurology|   
| 2  |   1  |nutrition|   
| 3  |   2  |kine     |   


session
| id |idProf|
........... 
| 1  |   1  | 
| 2  |   2  |  
| 3  |   3  |
```

According to the tables, professional 1, John, has 2 specialitys and has made 1 session, professional 2, Bart, has 1 speciality an 1 session and James, professional 3, has 0 spec, but 1 session.

What i need to do is to show professionals name and id of those who has made sessions and has, for example, more than 1 speciality, so it must select just
1, John

I'm working on sql.

i'm able to select data from those that has made sessions

```
SELECT pro.id, pro.name FROM professionals pro 
INNER JOIN session ssn
ON pro.id = ssn.idProf
```

and i can select values from speciality greater than X number

```
SELECT COUNT(speciality.profId) Q
FROM speciality
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(speciality.profId) > 1;
```

but i can't do both in same query

i hope it was the clearest possible

**EDIT**

My expected output, in this case...

```
| id | name | sessions Q|
........................
| 1  | John |     2     |
```

Comment: In this scenario, can you please add your expected output format

Comment: @Arulkumar
I expect to have, in this case
    id: 1, name: John,
because he is the only one tha has made sessions and has more than one speciality

Comment: Can you add the expected output as a sample table (like the input tables you show). The expected output should reflect what the sample inputs will produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JOIN and IN:

```
SELECT P.name, spec_count.Q
FROM professionals P
JOIN (
    SELECT profId, COUNT(profId) Q
    FROM speciality        
    GROUP BY profId
    HAVING COUNT(profId) > 1
) spec_count
ON P.id = spec_count.profId
WHERE P.id IN (SELECT idProf FROM session)
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ba37/2

Output:

```
| name | q |
|------|---|
| John | 2 |
```

Comment: I'm very begginer, can you please explain a little the code?
Where does that spec_count came from?

Comment: @Ron it's an alias for the JOIN'd query. You can make it explicit  by using `as`, e.g., `) as spec_count`

Comment: (don't know how to quote) i've just tested on the real problem and it works perfectly, but still i don't understand why jeje
I'll be reading this code tomorrow all day.
it's ok if i ask here some source where i can found some work out of this kind, with subqueries and so?
thanks a lot, btw

Comment: The subquery `spec_count` is an independent query, so it does not correlate with outside query. Query's independent-ness can be  emphasized better by moving it to a CTE. If you are using Postgres or MySQL 8  you can use CTE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ba37/6

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to include any of the subquery results later if you need.

```
SELECT pro.id, pro.name, Spec.SpecCount 
FROM professionals pro 
JOIN (SELECT profId
      FROM session
      GROUP BY profId) AS Session
ON pro.id = Session.ProfId
JOIN (SELECT profId, COUNT(1) AS SpecCount
      FROM speciality
      GROUP BY profId
      HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) AS Spec
ON pro.id = Spec.profId
```